# Change z-order of images

Tags: dart, flutter

I have three images that are stacked in a pile and slightly randomly rotated. Each image can be placed anywhere on the screen but as soon as an underlying image is touched, I'd like it to jump to the foreground and put the others underneath (just a 'bring-to-top'). Any suggestions how to accomplish this in Flutter?

A bit similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54491477/flutter-stack-with-two-images-in-gesturedetectors-problem-with-reordering) question but I'm not resizing or scaling.

**[UPDATE]**

I have updated my code to reflect the current situation. The clicked image now indeed jumps to the top but.... it will also take the *location* of the image currently on top (wherever you dragged it). For my purpose, it should stay in its original location so I guess I need to pass on the coordinates for the clicked image as well. Not sure how though...

My code so far for the working bits:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class myCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final Offset position;
  final double rotation;
  final String cardImage;
  final String value;
  final Function bringToTop;

  myCard({
    this.position,
    this.rotation,
    this.cardImage,
    this.value,
    this.bringToTop
  });

  @override
  myCardState createState() => myCardState();
}

class myCardState extends State<myCard> {
  Offset position;

  @override
  void initState() {
    position = widget.position;

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Positioned(
        left: position.dx,
        top: position.dy,
        child: GestureDetector(
            onPanStart: (details) {
              widget.bringToTop(widget);
            },
            onPanUpdate: (details) {
              setState(() {
                position = Offset(position.dx + details.delta.dx,
                    position.dy + details.delta.dy);
              });
            },
            child: _buildPart()
        ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildPart() {
    return  RotationTransition(
      turns: new AlwaysStoppedAnimation(widget.rotation),
      child: Container(
        width: 450,
        height: 600,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
          image: AssetImage(widget.cardImage),
              fit: BoxFit.cover),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

Random random = new Random();
int min = -5;
int max = 5;
int randomNumber1 = random.nextInt(max - min);
int randomNumber2 = random.nextInt(max - min);
int randomNumber3 = random.nextInt(max - min);

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<myCard> dragParts = [];

  double r1 = (min + randomNumber1) / 360;
  double r2 = (min + randomNumber2) / 360;
  double r3 = (min + randomNumber3) / 360;

  @override
  void initState() {
    dragParts = [];

    dragParts.add(myCard(
      position: Offset(700, 50),
      rotation: r1,
      cardImage: "assets/images/1.png",
      value: "1",
      bringToTop: this.bringToTop,
    ));

    dragParts.add(myCard(
      position: Offset(700, 50),
      rotation: r2,
      cardImage: "assets/images/2.png",
      value: "2",
      bringToTop: this.bringToTop,
    ));

    dragParts.add(myCard(
      position: Offset(700, 50),
      rotation: r3,
      cardImage: "assets/images/4.png",
      value: "4",
      bringToTop: this.bringToTop,
    ));


    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DecoratedBox(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage("assets/images/backgrnd.png"), fit: BoxFit.cover),
      ),
      child: Stack(
        children: dragParts,
      ),
    );
  }

  void bringToTop(Widget widget) {
    setState(() {
      dragParts.remove(widget);
      dragParts.add(widget);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: What you could do is put your elements in a `List`, reorder the List according to the last gesture (put the selected one first), and then draw the contents of that `List` again.

Comment: I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51031608/flutter-stack-change-depth) post but I've no clue how to apply that to my situation. I need to keep track of which one is dragged and the location it was clicked on (so the point of touch on the image).  But that's for another thread I think.